# TomlDecodeError: Key group not on a line by itself How to solve this problem when no toml file found?

Tags: python, config, streamlit, toml

dublicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59811357/how-to-solve-toml-decoder-tomldecodeerror-key-group-not-on-a-line-by-itself-l)

```
streamlit hello
```

Hello developers,

I am facing this issue ever since I tried to push my streamlit app onto heroku, which broke of course. You can find the error logs in the duplicate question, it's the same.

What I have tried to solve this:

1. Tried to find the `config.toml` file, but somehow couldn't able to find it. It's not where the streamlit is installed. There is no directory with the name `.streamlit`, there is `streamlit` and ``
2. Changed the executables, python3.7, python3.9, and separate virtual environment executable as well. Still it didn't work
3. installed the streamlit using

```
pip install --no-cache-dir streamlit
```

to get the fresh library modules, but still didn't work.

I don't know where is the issue, even after doing everything fresh new, the problem persist. I tried running the same script with my friend's device and it's working fine.

Any thoughts on this? Seems like something has broken with my device core files or what?

[community discussion on the topic](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/toml-docoder-error/1400/10)

Answer (score 0):

Run
`streamlit cache clear`

You will get output similar to this which will tell you where is your .streamlit directory exactly, take this path before the cache part.

> Nothing to clear at {Username}{path}.streamlit\cache.

`cd {Username}\{path}\.streamlit`

You'll be able to see config.toml here just delete that file.

Run `streamlit hello` to see the error resolved